# Xcode error breaking on release version of custom framework

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, frameworks

I am using the Release-iphoneos version of my custom framework in an app, I only added the Release-iphoneos binary, I didn't add the code to the project.

I had an error in the framework and Xcode stopped in the code of one of the objects of the framework, and all the code of that object was visible.

Is there some setting I am missing that would prevent the debugger from revealing my code?

UPDATE

In addition to the project I am working on, I have the framework project open in XCode, could that be the reason why it is stopping on the code?

Comment: Why don't you want to see your code? It doesn't mean other people would see it.

Comment: If the framework is provided to third parties, I don't want them to see the code.

Comment: Then don't give them code. It's not added to the framework unless you include it. You have the code so Xcode shows it. Move it elsewhere on disk and it won't if it's compiled correctly.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I didn't realize XCode would do that.

Answer (score 0):

If the framework is provided to third parties, I don't want them to see the code.
 – MSimic

Then don't give them code. It's not added to the framework unless you include it. You have the code so Xcode shows it. Move it elsewhere on disk and it won't if it's compiled correctly.
 – Sami Kuhmonen